# How to store search results and display data JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am stuck

I have two methods that NEEDS to be

```
public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
```

and

```
public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults)
```

both need to return void.

The only instance variable I am allowed to have is (not sure which one)

```
private ArrayList<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
```

or

```
private ArrayList<Property> properties;
```

I need to search an array list called properties and store the properties that fit within the price range in a LOCAL ArrayList that will then be passed to the displaySearchResults(ArrayList searchResults)  for display.

How would I create a local arraylist? How would I access the data in the local array list when calling the displaySearchReults method? How would I call the display search results method?

Right now, i think my searchByPriceRange method stores the data in a local variable called searchResults. But I dont understand how to call the displaySearchResults method and display the data in the local arraylist created in the searchByPriceRange method.

My full method in agentListings class

```
public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice){

    ArrayList<Property> searchResults;
    searchResults = new ArrayList<Property>();
    for (Property property : properties){
        if (property.getAskingPrice() > minPrice &&
                property.getAskingPrice() < maxPrice){

            searchResults.add(property);
        }
    }
}

public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults){


    for(Property result: searchResults) {

        System.out.println(result.getListingNumber());
    }
}
```

My driver class

```
AgentListings CharlesListings = new AgentListings();

CharlesListings.displaySearchResults(CharlesListings.searchByPriceRange(1, 2));
```

this line doesnt work. Not sure what to put in the param if the method param has to be

```
public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults)
```

Comment: Are you certain `searchByPriceRange` doesn't return an `ArrayList`? Also, why print the size of the `ArrayList` for each result? It will always be the same ;)

Comment: Or is it possible that the `displaySearchResults` method is not actually supposed to print anything but to fill the given parameter with the result of the search? The name would then be somewhat misleading, but it would avoid having to hand the object its own variable as a parameter and make more sense in that regard.

Comment: @Mark The instructions show a method with void but I am not sure if the instructions are wrong. Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I fixed it.

Comment: I am  trying to comprehend what your second comment is saying. Ill need to take some time. Thanks

Comment: these are the instructions to the assignment I am completing

Comment: https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=28ec9ed4-c6ef-445a-b842-1d59101661d3&fn=1409Assign3.pdf&ct=1594032383548&tl=share-document&rf=link

Comment: "public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults) Will display the property details of each searchResults ArrayList parameter." I still dont really understand the rationale of not using a print statement but I think the instructions sayI have to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the part that we overlooked in the instructions.

> public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice)
>
> Will search the ArrayList for properties where the asking
> price is between the minPrice and maxPrice, and add each match to a
> local ArrayList that will **then be passed to the**
> **displaySearchResults(ArrayList searchResults)  for display**

You did mention it in your question, but with everything else you wrote it kind of got me thinking in the wrong direction ;)

Which means:

```
public class AgentListings {
    private ArrayList<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();     
    
    public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice) {
        ArrayList<Property> searchResults = new ArrayList<Property>(); // <- This is your local ArrayList
        
        for (Property property : properties){
            if (property.getAskingPrice() >= minPrice && property.getAskingPrice() <= maxPrice) {
                searchResults.add(property);
            }
        }

        displaySearchResults(searchResults); // <- And here we go calling the method with the filtered list
    }

    public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults){
        System.out.println(searchResults.size());
        for(Property result: searchResults) { 
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The important part here is that we DO NOT change the properties our class remembers. We create a new local `ArrayList` and immediately display it.

Comment: Going to try to comprehend this, looks look this is going to bring a smile to my face. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring arrayList inside function, declare it in class like this

```
class{
    ArrayList<Property> searchResults = new ArrayList<Property>();

public void searchByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice){

   
    for (Property property : properties){
        if (property.getAskingPrice() > minPrice &&property.getAskingPrice() < maxPrice){
            this.searchResults.add(property); \\You can remove "this." as it may work without that
        }
    }
}

public void displaySearchResults(ArrayList<Property> searchResults){


    for(Property result: this.searchResults) { \\You can remove "this." as it may work without that

        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(searchResults.size());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how would I write the driving class? Also is declaring ArrayList outside the function local?

Comment: Not a bad answer, however it somewhat invalidates the parameter of `displaySearchResults`, because you no longer need (or want) it. It's very strange behaviour for a class to make the user hand its own `ArrayList` to one of its methods...

Comment: @GrantLee The `private` in front of your allowed instance variable suggests that it's supposed to be a class variable anyway. There's little sense in adding the `private` if you're declaring your `ArrayList` inside a method.

Comment: @Mark  How would I create a new local ArrayList without declaring the ArrayList inside the method? I am having a lot of trouble.

Comment: Exactly like Siddharth did it here (plus the private in front maybe ;)). That being said, I still think this can't be what whoever gave you this task had in mind, simply because the parameter becomes so useless... not that I can think of an alternative besides what I mentioned in the comments to your question...

Comment: I am  plucking my hairs out by the second

Comment: From the instructions @GrantLee linked to in his comments: `This new class will have one field, an ArrayList<Property> properties.` So yes, Siddarth did exactly what they wanted. I would remove the `this.` from the loop (like his comment suggests), just to be on the safe side (the instructions were very specific about the parameter being the one you're supposed to display here). It seems somewhat strange, but it looks like it is in fact what you were supposed to do.

Comment: @Mark so then that means the method displaySearchResults param has to be(ArrayList<Property>  properties)? But how would I separate the properties that are not in the price ranges?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217365/discussion-between-grant-lee-and-mark).